Is the discretisation formula of high dimension wrong?
In Terence Tao's book "An Introduction to Measure Theory" (Pg.6), the measure of a $d$-dimensional box $B$ is given by
$$
|B| = \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N^d}\#\left(B\cap\tfrac{1}{N}\mathbb Z^d\right),
$$
However, should it be written as the following instead?
$$
|B| = \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N^d}\#\left(B\cap\tfrac{1}{N^{\color{red}d}}\mathbb Z^d\right),
$$
i.e. should we also need $N^{\color{red}d}$ instead of $N$ inside the "$\#\left(...\right)$"?

Ordinarily, I would interpret $\frac{1}{a}\mathbb{Z}^d$ as the $d$-dimensional Euclidean lattice, scaled linearly by a factor of $\frac{1}{a}$. So no, I don't think you need $N^d$ there. Though, what is $I$ there?

@BrianTung That make sense. Thank you.
